# Correct syntax fro running a script via cron

Tags: php, .htaccess, cron

I need to check that I am doing this correct.

Have created two scripts to close and open a website

close.sh

```
mv /path/public_html/.htaccess  /path/public_html/.htaccess.bak
mv /path/public_html/.htaccess.temp  /path/public_html/.htaccess
```

open.sh

```
mv /path/public_html/.htaccess  /path/public_html/.htaccess.temp
mv /path/public_html/.htaccess.bak  /path/public_html/.htaccess
```

This will enable the .htaccess.temp file and then shortly after disable it.

I then ran crontab -e and set up

```
0 11 11 11 * /bin/sh /root/close.sh
02 11 11 11 * /bin/sh /root/open.sh
```

Am I correct in my crontabs? I saw some entries that have the /bin/sh and some that do not, so wasn't sure.

I am confident about my two scripts, I just need to ensure that they are run 2 minutes apart at 11am on 11th November each year.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You're correct, even if 0 is optional at the left of minutes:

```
0 11 11 11 * /bin/sh /root/close.sh
2 11 11 11 * /bin/sh /root/open.sh
```

From wikipedia:

```
 # * * * * *  command to execute
 # │ │ │ │ │
 # │ │ │ │ │
 # │ │ │ │ └───── day of week (0 - 6) (0 to 6 are Sunday to Saturday, or use names; 7 is Sunday, the same as 0)
 # │ │ │ └────────── month (1 - 12)
 # │ │ └─────────────── day of month (1 - 31)
 # │ └──────────────────── hour (0 - 23)
 # └───────────────────────── min (0 - 59)
```

Take care to set the right permissions to your .htaccess:

```
mv /path/public_html/.htaccess  /path/public_html/.htaccess.temp
mv /path/public_html/.htaccess.bak  /path/public_html/.htaccess
chown www-data:www-data /path/public_html/.htaccess
```

Comment: Thanks - am not familiar with www-data:www-data - what does that relate to?

Comment: `www-data` is the user who can access your `public_html` directory. If you put a crontab as root and put files into `public_html`, `www-data` may not be able to access them. We use `www-data:www-data` because the `www-data` user belongs to the `www-data` group. [More info](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/users_and_groups)

Answer (score 0):

You can verify your path of your "sh" binary with the command :

```
which sh
```

If the path returned is "/bin/sh", then you can let this path in your crontab.

Comment: Thanks. the path is correct, it was more a case of whether one should include it or not. I will leave it in.